# RequireJS: Best method to run page specific modules?

Tags: javascript, modularity, requirejs

**Example:**

`mysite.com/page1` depends on scripts in `module1.js`

`mysite.com/page2` depends on scripts in `module2.js`

`mysite.com/page3` depends on scripts in `module3.js`

Does anyone have any best practices for only running the Javascript required for that specific page. Before I started using RequireJS I would use only one Javascript file and init only the modules I needed for that page. like this

**In page** `<head>`:

```
var page = "pageTitle";
```

**In Main JS File:**

```
var myModules = {};

myModules.pageTitle = (function(){

    return {
          init: function(){
             alert('this module has been initiated');
          }
    }
})();


myModules[page].init();
```

*Not really sure sure how a technique like this would work with RequireJS. Would love some feedback and advice on how others are doing this.*

Answer (score 6):

I assume you have one main.js file for all your pages?

Anyway, typically you would use the *data-main* attribute of the script tag as explained in the API documentation, which would mean you have one main js file per page. This way, you can get rid of the literal javascript code in you page, and take full advantage of the RequireJS optimization step.

**Example:**

Develop you main.js file as a RequireJS module:

```
define([<dependencies go here>], function(){

    return function(pageTitle){
        //do you page dependent logic here
    }
}
```

In your html, you'll have something like:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="require.js"></script>
<script>
    require(["main.js"], function(init){
        init("pageTitle");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: ah ok I see. But isn't is best to serve only one file for the entire site?

Comment: Mmmm, that might make sense, definitely with the optimization step. 

You could also do the following in your html file:

    require(["main.js"], function(init){
        init("pageTitle");
    });

Comment: Could you expand on this concept?

Comment: Develop you main.js file as a RequireJS module:
`define([<dependencies go here>], function(){
`    return function(pageTitle){
`        //do you page dependent logic here
`    }
`}

In your html, you'll have something like:
`<html>
`<head>
`<script src="require.js"></script>
`<script>
` require(["main.js"], function(init){ init("pageTitle"); });
`</script>

Maybe we should set up a jsfiddle for this, as comments doesn't seem to be the right tool to discuss this ;)

Comment: I have edited your answer with your suggestion and created a JSFiddle of how I would like it to work: http://jsfiddle.net/WilsonPage/x543W/

Comment: This is how I would change it if you insist working with one js file:
http://jsfiddle.net/bertBruynooghe/ecjTt/1/

Comment: Not that ideal as every time I add a new module I will have to add it to the switch function too. Does your method get round this problem? Could you fiddle it up?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4780/discussion-between-bert-bruynooghe-and-pagewil)

Comment: I have added a second more detailed example. Is there a nicer way of doing this that dirty switch function? Something like `modules[CurrentPage].init();` ?

Comment: Could you incorporate points from comments into the answer? More explanation would be useful esp. around pageTitle parameter.

Answer (score 3):

1) What language do you use at back-end?

You can keep your script-configuration in database or in configuration files. (For example: page `page1` has modules: `module1`, `module2`, and `module4`, etc).

I have such a php template file for generating `<script>` tags on my page:

```
<script src="http://requirejs.org/docs/release/1.0.1/minified/require.js"></script>
<script>
    require([
        <?php echo "'". implode("',\n\t'", $this->scripts) . "'\n"; ?>
    ], function(a){

        function run(page) {
            if ( window.hasOwnProperty(page) ) {
                window[page].start();
            }
        }

        var page = '<?php echo $this->page; ?>';

        run('all'); // activating scripts needed for every page
        run(page); // and for current page
    });
</script>
```

P.S. the script is asking for window[page] variable. I meant, that every .js script for a page -- for example `index.js` for `index` page is making `window.index` variable. ( I know, it's not so good - read P.P.S ;) )

**P.P.S.** I'm novice to requireJS (I've knew about it only today), and it my first draft, and I think, I'll make it in another way:

2) As a concept for now :)
You keep your scripts as AMD modules (not as usual scripts, but as modules for requireJS). Modules map you can keep in a `.json` file:

```
{
    'index' : [ 'news', 'banners' ],
    'contacts' : [ 'maps', 'banners', 'donate' ],
    'otherpage' : [ 'module1', 'module2' ]
}
```

You should pass the page name or page id to the `main.js` (you can pass this value in DOM element - in templates of site, or in template variables ).
So `main.js` knows the page name, and load your `modules.json` file. It gets specific modules and `requires` them.

`main.js` also can keep dependencies that are need on every page ( for example jquery, some jquery plugins, etc) ( jquery plugins better to wrap as modules )

P.S. sorry for my English

Answer (score 3):

The creator of RequireJS actually made an example project doing excactly this: https://github.com/requirejs/example-multipage